# Merge existing list with an 'update' list

Tags: c#, list

I have two lists:
1) Existing list
2) Update list

Both lists contain a class of the following

```
public class Subcategory
{
  public int category_id { get; set; }
  public List<ProductInfo> products { get; set; }
  public List<Subcategory> subcategories { get; set; }
}
```

List 1:

```html
Subcat1
- Id: 1
- products:
  {product 1}
  {product 2}
- subcategories:
  {subcat2
   - Id: 2
   - products:
    {product 3}
   - subcategories:
    {subcat3
     - Id: 2
     - products:
      {product 4}
     - subcategories:
        {subcat4}
  }
```

List 2 is an update list, it contains new categories and products

```html
Subcat1
- Id: 1
- products:
  {product 5}
- subcategories:
  {subcat2
   - Id: 2
   - products:
    {product 6}
   - subcategories:
    {subcat5
     - Id: 5
     - products:
      {product 7}
  }
```

So what should happen:
- Add Product 5 to Subcat1
- Add Product 6 to Subcat1
- Add subcat5 to the list of categories of subcat2

I figured out how to update the existing items and remove delete items.
I have a list of int's that contain the id's of all the categories and one of all the products, if the current product orcategory is not in the respective list, it is deleted.
Recursively I also generated a list of all categories and all products that can be found in List2, called generatedCategories and generatedProducts.
Then, using follow code works for this update and delete behaviour:

```
private List<Product.Subcategory> UpdateObjects(List<Product.Subcategory> prod)
{
    try

    {
        int catcount = prod.Count;
        if (catcount > 0)
        {
            for (int i = catcount - 1; i > -1; i--)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Check if exists
                    if (categories.All(u => u.id != prod[i].category_id))
                    {
                        prod.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    //throw;
                }

                foreach (var newsubCat in generatedSubcategories)
                {
                    if (prod[i].category_id == newsubCat.category_id)
                    {
                        prod[i].delivery_time = newsubCat.delivery_time;
                        prod[i].image = newsubCat.image;
                        prod[i].name = newsubCat.name;
                        prod[i].pickup_time = newsubCat.delivery_time;
                        prod[i].sequence = newsubCat.sequence;
                        prod[i].translation_missing = newsubCat.translation_missing;
                        prod[i].use_firm_time_settings = newsubCat.use_firm_time_settings;
                    }
                }
                if (prod[i].products != null)
                {
                    foreach (var oldProduct in prod[i].products)
                    {
                        int count = generatedProducts.Count;
                        if (count != 0)
                        {
                            for (int z = count - 1; i > -1; i--)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    //Check if exists
                                    if (products.All(u => u.id != generatedProducts[z].id))
                                    {
                                        generatedProducts.RemoveAt(z);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (oldProduct.id == generatedProducts[z].id)
                                        {
                                            oldProduct.amount = generatedProducts[z].amount;
                                            oldProduct.comment = generatedProducts[z].comment;
                                            oldProduct.delivery_time = generatedProducts[z].delivery_time;
                                            oldProduct.description = generatedProducts[z].description;
                                            oldProduct.image = generatedProducts[z].image;
                                            oldProduct.ingredients = generatedProducts[z].ingredients;
                                            oldProduct.name = generatedProducts[z].name;
                                            oldProduct.pickup_time = generatedProducts[z].pickup_time;
                                            oldProduct.price = generatedProducts[z].price;
                                            oldProduct.sequence = generatedProducts[z].sequence;
                                            oldProduct.times = generatedProducts[z].times;
                                            oldProduct.translation_missing = generatedProducts[z].translation_missing;
                                            oldProduct.unit = generatedProducts[z].unit;
                                            oldProduct.use_category_time_settings = generatedProducts[z].use_category_time_settings;

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (Exception)
                                {

                                    //throw;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    if (prod[i].subcategories != null)
                    {
                        GenerateCategoryList(prod[i].subcategories);
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //throw;
    }
    return prod;
}
```

How would I go about adding the new categories and products in it's specified place?

Comment: Get the index of category 'AddAfterThisIndex' after which you want to add category, and then insert a category into list 'AddAfterThisIndex' + 1 using code someList.Insert('AddAfterThisIndex' + 1, newCategory);

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I'll post the solution when I find it.
Suggestions are still welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, thanks to the tip of Piyush I figured out a rough way (needs optimisation badly, but works generally):

1) Store your original list in a variable (oldList got passed from a different class)

```
    Subcategory OriginalList = new Subcategory();
    OriginalList = oldList;
```

2) Generate a dictionary containing all to-be-updated categories and products
'prod' is the base tree, and you will go recursively through it.

I added an extra field to the Subcategory class called parent_category_id, which stores the parent id obviously, you pass this to the function each iteration.
generatedProducts and generatedSubcategories is needed for updating the existing items later.

```
    List<Product.ProductInfo> generatedProducts = new List<Product.ProductInfo>();
    List<Product.Subcategory> generatedSubcategories = new List<Product.Subcategory>();
    Dictionary<int, List<Product.Subcategory>> dicCategories = new Dictionary<int, List<Product.Subcategory>>();
    Dictionary<int, List<Product.ProductInfo>> dicProducts = new Dictionary<int, List<Product.ProductInfo>>();

    private List<Product.Subcategory> GenerateProductList(List<Product.Subcategory> prod, int parentCategoryId)
    {
        foreach (var subcategory in prod)
        {
            generatedSubcategories.Add(subcategory);
            if (dicCategories.ContainsKey(subcategory.category_id))
            {
                //Add to value
                subcategory.parent_category_id = parentCategoryId;
                dicCategories[subcategory.category_id].Add(subcategory);
            }
            else
            {
                subcategory.parent_category_id = parentCategoryId;
                dicCategories.Add(subcategory.category_id, new List<Product.Subcategory> { subcategory });
            }

            if (subcategory.products != null)
            {
                foreach (var product in subcategory.products)
                {
                    generatedProducts.Add(product);
                    if (dicProducts.ContainsKey(subcategory.category_id))
                    {
                        //Add to value
                        dicProducts[subcategory.category_id].Add(product);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dicProducts.Add(subcategory.category_id, new List<Product.ProductInfo>{ product });
                    }
                } 
            }
            if (subcategory.subcategories != null)
            {
                GenerateProductList(subcategory.subcategories, subcategory.category_id);
            }
        }
        return prod;
    }
```

3) Call the GenerateProductList to fill the lists with the new data, use parent id 0 to say it's the root.

```
GenerateProductList(yourNewDataList, 0);
```

4) Okay, now it's time to create a list with the new items and old items combined.

```
    Product NewList = new Product();
    private void AddNewItems()
    {
        NewList.data = new List<Product.Subcategory>();
        foreach (var subcat in OriginalList.data)
        {
            if (!NewList.data.Any(c => c.category_id == subcat.category_id))
            {
                NewList.data.Add(subcat);
            }

        }

        Product tempList = Product.DeepCopy(NewList);


        foreach (var cat in dicCategories)
        {
            foreach (var toAdd in cat.Value)
            {
                if (toAdd.parent_category_id == 0)
                {
                    //Root
                    if (!NewList.data.Any(c => c.category_id == toAdd.category_id))
                    {
                        tempList.data.Add(toAdd);
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    foreach (var subcat in OriginalList.data)
                    {
                        Product.Subcategory y = Product.FindSubCat(subcat, toAdd.parent_category_id);
                        if (y != null)
                        {
                            Product.Subcategory x = BrowseCategories(subcat, toAdd);
                            int index = NewList.data.IndexOf(subcat);
                            tempList.data[index] = x;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        NewList = tempList;

        foreach (var product in dicProducts)
        {

            foreach (var subcat in NewList.data)
            {
                foreach (var subproduct in product.Value)
                {
                    Product.Subcategory y = Product.FindSubCat(subcat, product.Key);
                    if (y != null)
                    {
                        Product.Subcategory x = BrowseProducts(subcat, subproduct, product.Key);
                        int index = NewList.data.IndexOf(subcat);
                        tempList.data[index] = x;
                        x = x;
                    }

                    //tempList.data[subcat] =
                }
            }
        }
        NewList = tempList;
    }
    private Product.Subcategory BrowseProducts(Product.Subcategory category, Product.ProductInfo toAdd, int catId)
    {
        try
        {
            if (category.category_id == catId)
            {
                if (category.products == null) category.products = new List<Product.ProductInfo>();
                var remove = category.products.SingleOrDefault(s => s.id == toAdd.id);
                if (remove != null)
                {
                    if (remove.id != 0)
                    {
                        category.products.Remove(remove);
                    }
                }
                category.products.Add(toAdd);
                return category;
            }
            if (category.products == null) return category;
            if (category.subcategories == null) return category;
            foreach (var cat in category.subcategories)
            {
                if (cat.category_id == catId)
                {
                    if (cat.products == null) cat.products = new List<Product.ProductInfo>();
                    var remove = cat.products.SingleOrDefault(s => s.id == toAdd.id);
                    if (remove != null)
                    {
                        if (remove.id != 0)
                        {
                            cat.products.Remove(remove);
                        }
                    }
                    cat.products.Add(toAdd);
                    return category;
                }
                BrowseProducts(cat, toAdd, catId);

            }
            return category;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    } 


    private Product.Subcategory BrowseCategories(Product.Subcategory category, Product.Subcategory toAdd)
    {
        try
        {
            if (category.category_id == toAdd.parent_category_id)
            {
                if (category.subcategories == null) category.subcategories = new List<Product.Subcategory>();
                var remove = category.subcategories.SingleOrDefault(s => s.category_id == toAdd.category_id);
                if (remove != null)
                {
                    if (remove.category_id != 0)
                    {
                        category.subcategories.Remove(remove);
                    }
                }
                category.subcategories.Add(toAdd);
                return category;
            }
            if (category.subcategories == null) return category;
            foreach (var cat in category.subcategories)
            {
                if (cat.category_id == toAdd.parent_category_id)
                {
                    if (cat.subcategories == null) cat.subcategories = new List<Product.Subcategory>();
                    var remove = cat.subcategories.SingleOrDefault(s => s.category_id == toAdd.category_id);
                    if (remove != null)
                    {
                        if (remove.category_id != 0)
                        {
                            cat.subcategories.Remove(remove);
                        }
                    }
                    cat.subcategories.Add(toAdd);
                    return category;
                }
                BrowseCategories(cat, toAdd);

            }
            return category;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
```

5) Great! NewList now contains all the old and new data, but we still have to update the old data.

```
    private List<Product.Subcategory> UpdateObjects(List<Product.Subcategory> prod)
    {
        try

        {
            int catcount = prod.Count;
            if (catcount > 0)
            {
                for (int i = catcount - 1; i > -1; i--)
                {
                    //if (prod[i].category_id == 203)
                    //{
                    //    Debug.WriteLine("");
                    //}
                    try
                    {
                        //Check if exists
                        if (categories.All(u => u.id != prod[i].category_id))
                        {
                            //if (prod[i].category_id == 203)
                            //{
                            //    prod.RemoveAt(i);
                            //}
                            if (!dicCategories.ContainsKey(prod[i].category_id))
                            {
                                prod.RemoveAt(i);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                        //throw;
                    }

                    foreach (var newsubCat in generatedSubcategories)
                    {
                        if (prod[i].category_id == newsubCat.category_id)
                        {
                            prod[i].delivery_time = newsubCat.delivery_time;
                            prod[i].image = newsubCat.image;
                            prod[i].name = newsubCat.name;
                            prod[i].pickup_time = newsubCat.delivery_time;
                            prod[i].sequence = newsubCat.sequence;
                            prod[i].translation_missing = newsubCat.translation_missing;
                            prod[i].use_firm_time_settings = newsubCat.use_firm_time_settings;
                        }
                    }
                    if (prod[i].products != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var oldProduct in prod[i].products)
                        {
                            int count = generatedProducts.Count;
                            if (count != 0)
                            {
                                for (int z = count - 1; i > -1; i--)
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        //Check if exists
                                        if (products.All(u => u.id != generatedProducts[z].id))
                                        {
                                            generatedProducts.RemoveAt(z);
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            if (oldProduct.id == generatedProducts[z].id)
                                            {
                                                oldProduct.amount = generatedProducts[z].amount;
                                                oldProduct.comment = generatedProducts[z].comment;
                                                oldProduct.delivery_time = generatedProducts[z].delivery_time;
                                                oldProduct.description = generatedProducts[z].description;
                                                oldProduct.image = generatedProducts[z].image;
                                                oldProduct.ingredients = generatedProducts[z].ingredients;
                                                oldProduct.name = generatedProducts[z].name;
                                                oldProduct.pickup_time = generatedProducts[z].pickup_time;
                                                oldProduct.price = generatedProducts[z].price;
                                                oldProduct.sequence = generatedProducts[z].sequence;
                                                oldProduct.times = generatedProducts[z].times;
                                                oldProduct.translation_missing = generatedProducts[z].translation_missing;
                                                oldProduct.unit = generatedProducts[z].unit;
                                                oldProduct.use_category_time_settings = generatedProducts[z].use_category_time_settings;

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception)
                                    {

                                        //throw;
                                    }


                                }
                            }

                        }

                        if (prod[i].subcategories != null)
                        {
                            UpdateObjects(prod[i].subcategories);
                        }


                    }
                }
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            //throw;
        }

        return prod;
    }
```

Call the function:

```
    List<Product.Subcategory> completedList = UpdateObjects(addedList.data);
```

Now completedList contains all the new, old and updated items!

Suggestions on improving this are still welcome tho.